# Saving files to another web application running in the same Tomcat Instance (Not working)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have 3 web apps running on the same tomcat instance, one app (**ZaapMartAdmin**) is for the admin to upload files to another app's (**ImageUploads**) directory, while the third app (**ROOT**) is simply to read the files uploaded to (**ImageUploads**) and display the image files from there.
I got some ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197784/transferring-files-between-web-applications-running-in-the-same-tomcat-instance), [here](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-obtain-servletcontext-of-another-application/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834016/how-to-access-the-one-web-application-context-in-another-web-application-context), and [here](https://blog.imaginea.com/cross-context-communication-between-web-applications/).

Here's the relevant code in my servlet (Please note: servlet is running on **ZaapMartAdmin**):

```
//...
String fileName = generateFileName(request);//Generate the image file name
byte[] imageBytes = getByteArray(request);//Generate the image bytes
//Where to save the image part
ServletContext adminContext = request.getServletContext();//ZaapMartAdmin context
ServletContext rootContext = adminContext.getContext("/");//ROOT context
ServletContext uploadsContext = rootContext.getContext("/ImageUploads");//ImageUploads context
String absolutePath = uploadsContext.getRealPath("");
File imagesDirectory = new File(absolutePath + File.separator + "images");
if(!imagesDirectory.exists())
            imagesDirectory.mkdir();
try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(absolutePath + File.separator + "images" + File.separator + fileName);)
{
      fos.write(imageBytes);//<-- store the image in the directory
      //... store file name to database ...
}
//...
```

From the server end my directory structure looks like this:

[image]

The problem now is, when I run this servlet, the files will be saved inside the "**ZaapMartAdmin**" directory instead of the "**ImageUploads**" directory.
And it doesn't throw any Exceptions.

Also I have added `crossContext="true"` in the context.xml of each of the apps.

Please what I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: Simply save the files in an external directory. That way the will not be deleted, if you redeploy your apps.

Comment: That will be awesome but how can I go about that without passing through an app?

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path, like: ´new File(/var/tomcat/data/images);´?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research on the [tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html) about Contexts, I was able to deduce that the solution to the problem was to add a new Context tag to the Host tag in my tomcat/conf/server.xml file:

```
      <Host name="admin.zaapmart.com"  appBase="webapps/zaapmart.com/ZaapMartAdmin"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
        <Alias>www.admin.zaapmart.com</Alias>
        <Context path="" reloadable="true" docBase="/home/royalsee/tomcat/webapps/zaapmart.com/ZaapMartAdmin" crossContext="true"/>
        <!-- next line of code did the trick -->
        <Context path="/ImageUploads" reloadable="true" docBase="/home/royalsee/tomcat/webapps/zaapmart.com/ImageUploads" crossContext="true"/>
      </Host>
```

and I modified my servlet code to this:

```
//...
String fileName = generateFileName(request);//Generate the image file name
byte[] imageBytes = getByteArray(request);//Generate the image bytes
//Where to save the image part
ServletContext adminContext = request.getServletContext();//ZaapMartAdmin context
ServletContext uploadsContext = adminContext.getContext("/ImageUploads");//ImageUploads context
String absolutePath = uploadsContext.getRealPath("");
File imagesDirectory = new File(absolutePath + File.separator + "images");
if(!imagesDirectory.exists())
    imagesDirectory.mkdir();
try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(absolutePath + File.separator + "images" + File.separator + fileName);)
{
      fos.write(imageBytes);//<-- store the image in the directory
      //... store file name to database ...
}
//...
```

After that I restarted the tomcat server and everything worked the way I wanted!